# Add vertical lines to time-series plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I have the code below which plots two time-series.  I'd like to add a vertical line every say 10 units on the x-axis to basically divide the plot up into like 5 squares.  Any tips are very much appreciated.

```
Code:
## Plot Forecast & Actual
  ts.plot(ts(CompareDf$stuff1),ts(CompareDf$stuff2),col=1:2,xlab="Hour",ylab="Minu    tes",main='testVar')
legend("topleft", legend = c("Actual","Forecast"), col = 1:2, lty = 1)

Data:
dput(CompareDf)
structure(list(stuff1 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 
48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55), stuff2 = c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57)), .Names = c("stuff1", 
"stuff2"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First find the total number of lines required `n <- floor(max(CompareDf$stuff1,CompareDf$stuff2)/10)`. Next use `abline` to plot them `abline(v= seq(10, (n*10), 10))` after your `ts.plot()`

Comment: @KarthikArumugham  Thank you, that totally did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plotting timeseries data, use `abline` to draw vertical lines.

```
abline(v = seq(10, 50, 10))
```

[image]